# Using SignedJwtAssertionCredentials on Python Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Used the code snippet below to edit cells of a spreadsheet on my google drive account. This works when i run the code from my python IDE (Not on google app engine).

```
import webapp2
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
import json
from httplib2 import Http
from gspread.exceptions import CellNotFound
import os

# folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# file_path = os.path.join(folder, 'clientkey.json')
json_key = json.load(open('clientkey.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
googleClient = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

On copying same code to my google app engine project which i am to deploy, it shows the error below.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle

    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler

    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject

    obj = __import__(path[0])

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\DominicProject\main.py", line 3, in <module>

    from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\DominicProject\oauth2client\client.py", line 34, in <module>

    import six

ImportError: No module named six
```

I added the module required, it throw an error saying another module is required. Kept on adding the required modules and it keep on throwing error to add other module. Have added over 8 modules just to make it work and it still saying some modules an not be found even while it works well outside appengine. How do i fix this.

Comment: The code can work because some modules exist on your machine but not on the instance that handles your application. I would suggest finishing adding all the modules and then see what's happening after it's all handled. If you still have an error then, this is the right place to ask your question

Answer (score 0):

I see this is and older question but unanswered and still getting views. This will happen if you only install the client library to your system site-packages like this:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

To vendor the library along with all its required dependencies into your app's directory in one go, so that they will be uploaded along with your application, use the '-t' flag:

```
pip install google-api-python-client -t /myappdir
```